# [dotNET Core]Passing model to view -> bind checkbox with it's data in POST method form -> sending whole model to controller

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need some help. I am trying to pass **ShowSeatsViewModel** to **Seats.cshtml** bind it with passed view model's field and send it back with new values to controller.

ViewModel :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace theatre_dotNET.Models
{
    public class SpectacleShowsViewModel : Spectacle
    {
        public List<Show> IncomingShows { get; set; }
        public Show pickedShow { get; set; }
        public int[] availableSeats { get; set; }
        public int[] bookedSeats { get; set; }
        public SpectacleShowsViewModel(Spectacle s, List<Show> incomingShows)
        {
            this.SpectacleId = s.SpectacleId;
            this.Title = s.Title;
            this.Description = s.Description;
            this.Price = s.Price;
            this.VideoLink = s.VideoLink;
            this.Rating = s.Rating;
            IncomingShows = incomingShows;
        }
    }
}
```

Two methods of controller :

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Seats(Show chosenShow)
{
    int[] availableSeats = _context.Seats.Select(s => s.SeatId).ToArray();
    int[] bookedSeats = _context.BookedSeats.Where(i => i.ShowId == chosenShow.ShowId).Select(s => s.SeatId).ToArray();

    return View(new ShowSeatsViewModel(chosenShow, availableSeats, bookedSeats));
}

[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Seats(ShowSeatsViewModel chosenShowSeatsViewModel)
{
    return Content("Picked seats : "+chosenShowSeatsViewModel.PickedSeats);
}
```

View:

```
@model ShowSeatsViewModel

<h1>Chosen Spectacle : Model.SpectacleId</h1>
<form asp-controller="Booking" asp-action="Seats" method="post">
<div class="row">
@foreach(var seat in Model.AvailableSeats)
{
    @if(Model.UnavailableSeats.Contains(@seat))
    {
        <div class="col">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.PickedSeats[@seat-1])
            @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.PickedSeats[@seat-1],@seat.ToString())
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="col">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(mdl => mdl.PickedSeats[@seat-1])
            @Html.LabelFor(mdl => mdl.PickedSeats[@seat-1],@seat.ToString())
        </div>
    }
}
</div>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And an error - after choosing checkboxes and clicking submit button:

```
InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'theatre_dotNET.Models.ShowSeatsViewModel'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. Alternatively, give the 'chosenShowSeatsViewModel' parameter a non-null default value.
```

How could I send existing(passed from Controller) ViewModel via post method? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I'm updating my answer.

In your case, you can't model bind to that Object without custom model binding.

1. It's a complex object that doesn't have a parameterless constructor.
2. You need to have all of the properties in the form to pass the entire model with. As you stated that's not what you want.

In your case a custom model binder is a complex implementation that you would have to do over and over throughout the app. I wouldn't recommend this approach.

On the client side I would use a library like `JQUERY` to perform the post for complex objects.

Here is an example.

1. Create a `JS` script to run these `POST` requests with complex objects with the following function.

Here is an example with `JQuery`

```
function ajaxRequest(httpVerb, url, model, onSuccess, onFail, onComplete) {
    if (httpVerb === null || httpVerb.length === 0) httpVerb = "POST";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: httpVerb,
        cache: false,
        traditional: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }).done(function (data) {
       //onSuccess()...
    }).fail(function (err) {
       //onFail()...
    }).always(function (data) {
       //onComplete()...
    });
}
```

Here is how you would call it

```
     var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); //this gets your view model and converts it to a JS object. 
     //Or you can take the time and create it manually
     var model = {...}

        //take the form values and replace the model properties as needed
        // make sure to give your HTML elements in the forms ID attributes so you can select them.
        model.PickedSeats = $('#myCheckboxById').is(':checked');
        ...
        // do the same with the other form values

        ajaxRequest("POST", "/Booking/Seats", model , null, null, null);
        //the null values being passed in are the callback functions you would perform in the method signature. I just left them null to simplify things.
```

Comment: I dont understand the question " Also What does SpectacleShowsViewModel have to do with ShowSeatsViewModel?". I'll check your answer in a moment.

Comment: Made another edit. Make sure you `ShowSeatsViewModel` class has a parameterless constructor. You can't model bind to a constructor with paramters like that.

Comment: I asked the question because I don't see you using it in the code.

Comment: I am using it - I am passing it from public IActionResult Seats(Show chosenShow) as return View(new ShowSeatsViewModel(chosenShow, availableSeats, bookedSeats));. After than I am using it in the Seats view and would like to send it back with modified values of ShowSeatsViewModel.PickedSeats array.

Comment: Binding it to "new ShowSeatsViewModel()" clears other data passed to view inside my ShowSeatsViewModel from controller(where it has been created). I am trying to return it back just with modified values of this ViewModel.

[FromBody] provides HTTP ERROR 415 after submitting a form.

Comment: That's supposed to happen because that's what you're posting back. I would suggest 3 ways to do this. Make an `AJAX POST` request with the complex object (best bet). 2. Make a bunch of hidden fields on the form and post all of it. 3. Use something like TempData to pass the object between requests.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give me an example how could I do it with first method? I have never used AJAX requests before. Would be really helpful if you could provide simple example as an answer. I was trying to avoid second method.

Comment: Sure, are you using Javascript or Typescript on the front end? Or would you rather just keep it in razor syntax?

Comment: Also what version of asp.net core mvc are you using?

Comment: I'd like to keep it in razor pages. Would be great. Dotnet version 3.0.100.

Comment: I'll try to post an answer today if I have time. If not I'll show an example tomorrow morning.

Comment: Just for reference you would need to do something like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53181095/model-binding-of-nested-properties-in-asp-net-core-2-2.