# problem in Binding a view model that is in another view model

Tags: asp.net-core, data-binding, bind, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

To display the information of two tables that are related one to one, I need to implement view models as follows:

```cs
public class EstateViewModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public EstateInfoViewModel InfosModel { get; set; } = new EstateInfoViewModel();
}

public class EstateViewModel
{
    public string Describe{ get; set; }
}
```

After defining the view models, I put the HTML codes in the view as below:

```
@Html.TextboxFor(x => x.Name);
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.InfosModel.Describe)
```

After execution, the names of the text boxes will be displayed in the browser as follows:

```html
<input id="Id" name="Id" type="text">
<input id="Name" name="Name" type="text">
<input id="Describe" name="Describe" type="text">
```

My problem is that the "describe" textbox is not binding to `InfosModel.Describe` in the action because its name in the view is `Describe` and not `InfosModel.Describe`

I tried `use new {id="GiveName", Name = "GiveName"}` but it doesn't work and doesn't change the name of `Describe` property.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Model binding of nested properties in asp.net core 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53181095/model-binding-of-nested-properties-in-asp-net-core-2-2)